# How do you create the vertical endless scrolling view in HTC WorldClock.apk, when setting the alarm?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, alarm

In the WorldClock.apk of a HTC Sense Android phone, when a user wants to set the alarm, the user would see a black pop-up showing three vertical dials (value pickers, value selectors, etc). Those three vertical dials all can scroll up/down and cycle through the valid values.

One is for hours, one is for minutes, and one is for AM or PM. There are no button, other than Done and Cancel. The vertical scrolling sliders is the one thing I'm looking for in the Android SDK Reference, and is the one I wanted to create.

1. What are the vertical scrolling dials (number picker, sliding thing) called? What name?
2. What class should I use to create it in Java?
3. Is there anything else like it?

Note, it is not for Windows Phone. It's an Android phone with the HTC Sense app, WorldClock.apk.

Also note that I'm trying to obtain a picture of the Alarm Clock sliders on my HTC phone. But it's really hard when no one else has a digital camera for me to borrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose what you want is a wheel like this:
http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/

I have use it in my project, really help.

Comment: Looks like it fits everything I asked for. Thanks.